# How to model coin-flips with pymc (from Probabilistic Programming and Bayesian Methods for Hackers)

Tags: bayesian, pymc

Basically asking about https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/issues/150

At https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter2_MorePyMC/Ch2_MorePyMC_PyMC2.ipynb the author discusses a model where students are asked if they cheated on a test or not. They flip coins and answer honestly if heads, otherwise answer randomly. Given the number of "yes" answers, how can we get the distribution of cheaters?

The author there basically models this arising from a probability of cheaters, which will give rise to some set of observations of students either cheating or not, which will then give rise to some set of answers via the coin flips, which will then yield some observed probability of answering, "yes, I cheated."

However, instead of letting that observed probability (or just the sum of "yes") answers be the observation, he THEN models a binomial distribution on top of that, and the observation recorded in the experiment is set as the observed value for that distribution.

My questions:

1. Is this the right thing to do? If so, why?
2. Assuming it's not, is there a better solution (short of the radically simplified version he presents)?

The general case of this is having an "observed" value for a sum of random variables. People online seem to suggest this is impossible, but I don't get why you couldn't just, e.g., "observe" a draw from a uniform distribution with the mean at your deterministic observation and bounds at +/- epsilon.

Answer (score 0):

Prob/Stat problems are subtle. If I am reading your question correctly; The choice between binomial and uniform distros have to do with the significance of the latter part of the scenario setup.. It say's if the students flip tails, they can answer randomly.  This means that an answer of `no` is not equally likely as `yes` because while a coin flip is uniformly distributed, the following answers are not.

If the student absolutely HAD to answer 'no' on tails, you could definitely use another uniform distribution.  Hope that helps!